# How to read pickled utf-8 dataframe on google-colaboratory

Tags: pandas, utf-8, google-colaboratory

I made a pickled utf-8 dataframe on my local machine.

I can read this pickled data with `read_pickle` on my local machine.

However, I cannot read it **on google-colaboratory**.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`

**Postscript01**

My code is very simple

```
import pandas as pd
DF_OBJ = open('/content/drive/DF_OBJ')
DF = pd.read_pickle(DF_OBJ)
```

I can run until 2nd row.

I cannot run the last row with the above error comment.

**Postscript02**

I could solve it by myself.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle5
DF_OBJ = open('OBJ','rb')
DF = pickle5.load(DF_OBJ)
```

Comment: Please add your code, what you tried till

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I posted the code.